# Angular2 simplest server

Tags: node.js, angular

I have a problem with configuring project in Angular2 so it works.
I did the tutorial, `Tour of Heroes` on angular site and it uses `lite-server`.
Now, this is perfect for me, I don't want anything complicated - simplest server, because all of my backend logic is elsewhere.

I tried to deploy it to server but it won't run. Also, on github page of lite-server it says `Lightweight development only node server`.

I tried express and webpack but those are extremely complicated, with advanced routing and stuff like that. I don't know how  I can simply port what worked on light-server to those servers.

Is there any server like `light-server` which I can run in production? Or any simples seed, that isn't full-blown node server?

Comment: Any static HTTP server can be used ;-) Could you give us more details about your errors behind "it won't run"? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps need to alter the `href` in the `<base>` tag in the `index.html`. Other than that, more information might be required to actually be able to help you

Comment: Yes agreed with you @PierreDuc! This looks like a path issue ;-)